# No module named slack

Tags: python, django, django-allauth, slack

I'm trying test [django-allauth/example] from https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth.

follow the [example/readme.rst], all steps need to test the exmaple as follows:

```
$ git clone git://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth.git
$ cd django-allauth/example
$ virtualenv venv
$ . venv/bin/activate
$ pip install -r requirements.txt

$ python manage.py migrate  # **The promblem happen here**

$ python manage.py createsuperuser
$ python manage.py runserver
```

When i migrate database by command "$ python manage.py migrate", an [ImportError] appears with description: "no module named slack"

I have search on google but there no standard [slack package] for python or any infomation about [slack]. So, there ís no way to fix the problem for me.

What the [slack] is and how can i pass it? Help me.

Comment: Can you search for word slack in your source code? Also can you paste the error message?

Comment: How can i search word slack in source code? The error message just what I've said: "ImportError: No module named slack".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you've edited your settings.py in accordance with the documentation found here: https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html. Particularly including 'allauth.socialaccount.providers.slack'.

Comment: yes, it help. The problem in setting file. I just delete all socialaccount provider. Thanks you so much.

Comment: sorry, i could not, because i have not enough reputation :))

Comment: when i have enough, I will come back and vote, I promise

Comment: Haha. Don't worry about it!

Comment: @VuHa just for your information accepting and upvoting answers are different, see [accepting answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) and [tour] for more info. You can always accept if you are the one who wrote the question, there is just a time frame if you self answer